# Python read file line by line and convert to dictionary

Tags: python

I have below data in file.sec:

```
goog,100
goog,101
goog,103
micro,200
micro,201
face,99
```

I want to convert this data into a dictionary:
{'goog' : [100,101,103] , 'micro' : [200 , 201] , 'face' : [99]}

I tried below code, but it wipes out the list whenever value changes from goog to micro and result I get is: {'goog' : [99] , 'micro' : [99] , 'face':[99]}

```
allD = {}
allN = []
f = open('file.sec' , 'r')
for data in f:
   com = data.split(',')[0]
   
   if com not in allD.keys():
      del allN[:]

   allN.append( data.split(',')[1] )

   allD[ com ] = allN  
    
 print allD
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a defaultdict to solve this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data_dict = defaultdict(list)

f = open('file.sec' , 'r')
for data in f:
    key, value = data.split(',')
    data_dict[key].append(value)
```

Note that i've written this in python 3 syntax, so you may need to do it slightly differently for python 2.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

f = open('file.sec' , 'r')
for data in f:
    com = data.split(',')[0]
    result[com].append(data.split(',')[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not far, but there is a misunderstanding on what a Python assignment is. When you write `allD[ com ] = allN`, `allD[com]` is not a copy of `allN` but is just another reference to the very same object. So when you later clean `allN` with `del allN[:]` you actually clean the last `allD[com]`. You should instead use a new object:

```
allD = {}
allN = []
f = open('file.sec' , 'r')
for data in f:
   com = data.split(',')[0]
   
   if com not in allD.keys():
      allN = []
      allD[ com ] = allN  

   allN.append( data.split(',')[1] )

    
 print allD
```

Answer (score 0):

An example without defaultdict :

```
allD = {}
allN = []
f = open('data.csv', 'r')
for data in f:
    com = data.split(',')[0]

    if com not in allD.keys():
        allD[com] = []

    allD[com].append(data.split(',')[1].strip())

print(allD)
```

Comment: Instead of using replace, we should use strip()